# Access SQL Year Function Compile Error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying pull the year out of the date field, CPARS.[Add Date]. The format is (MM/DD/YYYY). It is giving me a "compile error in query expression year.(CPARS.[Add Date])". Why might it be doing this?

```
SELECT CPARS.ID, YEAR(CPARS.[Add Date])
FROM CPARS
```

Ive tried all the other date functions: year, month, day, datepart, datediff in many examples and I still get a compile error. The data type is Date/Time.

Out of curiosity I attempted the count function and it worked perfectly. All date functions are not working.

Comment: A compile error on inbuilt functions can be caused by broken references, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27350292/3820271

Comment: Also possibly useful: [Decompile](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3268188/3820271)

Comment: Your error says `year.(CPARS.[Add Date])`. Note the period after `year.` -
 check if that is also there in your actual code, it probably should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **DatePart**:

```
SELECT CPARS.ID, DatePart("yyyy",[Add Date])
FROM CPARS
```

Comment: @PrestonRichardson did you verify that the [Add Date] field is of the date/time data type with the format set to Short Date? Also, are you sure there is no record in the table for which this field contains bad data or nulls?

Comment: @PrestonRichardson I was able to get this to run correctly in a test table: `SELECT CPARS.ID, DatePart('yyyy',[CPARS]![Add Date]) AS Expr1
FROM CPARS;`

Comment: Doubled checked and the field is data/time data type with short date format. Tried the last code and still got the compile error. Must be an underlying problem and not the code

Comment: @PrestonRichardson the only other thing I could find that is not code related is [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d857e99c-7fe8-4308-b098-259643f6d9d9/how-do-i-fix-compile-error-in-query-expression-date?forum=accessdev)

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
SELECT CPARS.ID, datepart(yyyy,CPARS.[Add Date])
FROM CPARS
```

Is 'CPARS.[Add Date]' actually a date field? Or is it a varchar or something?

Comment: It is an actual date field. The data type is date/time formatted for short date. I keep getting the compile error regardless of the code used so it must be a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two reasons:

1. You have missed references.
   Solution:
   Open Visual Basic editor (Alt+F11): Tools->References
   Uncheck all references like: "MISSING: ...".
2. The error can appear on 64 bit computers with an old Visual Basic code.
   Solution:
   You have to add "PtrSafe" commands.
   Open Visual Basic editor (Alt+F11).
   Compile your code: Debug->Compile.
   The Access shows you where PtrSafe command should be added.